# How can I create a button with a background color for tvOS while still showing focus?

Tags: uibutton, tvos

All I want to do is add a background color to a button for all states. But I want to maintain the automatic focus shadow that you get "for free" when using a system button in the `tvOS` storyboard. So far I haven't been able to find a combination that allows this.

Alternatively, I would also be interested in a way to programmatically add the shadow when the button is focused, but short of subclassing the button (which I haven't yet tried), I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: The reason this is particularly frustrating is that if you add the shadow programmatically, you lose all the cool half-motion bounciness.

Comment: An apple engineer (on the dev forums) said you can reproduce the motion using the new `UIMotionEffect` API: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/index.html I'm not sure how, but I might play with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `didUpdateFocusInContext` method and check if next focus view is button, if yes then customize its UI, and to set it back to orignal state check `context.previousFocusedView` was that button, something like below

```c
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (context.nextFocusedView == _button)
    {
        // set background color
    }
    else if (context.previousFocusedView == _button)
    {
        // set background color to background
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing yesterday. I would still like to know if my first question is possible.

Comment: This doesn't work. You still can't override the white background color that gets added to the focused button.

Comment: Orignal question was how to change the background color of button, not the focus color, and answer is solution for that

Comment: No, the original question was a background color for all states, focused and not. Ideally, the shadow would indicate focused state.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a shadow for your custom button like this:

```c
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 10);
    context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
    context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
    context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    context.previouslyFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Wasn't happy with a simple colour change, so I made a custom button subclass to look more like the default animation you get with system buttons -

```c
class CustomButton: UIButton
{
    private var initialBackgroundColour: UIColor!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initialBackgroundColour = backgroundColor
    }

    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
    {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations(
        {
            if self.focused
            {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations:
                {
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
                },
                completion: 
                {
                    finished in

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations:
                    {
                        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    },
                    completion: nil)
                })
            }
            else
            {
                self.backgroundColor = self.initialBackgroundColour
            }
        },
        completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Nothing too complicated, but gets the job done

Answer (score 4):

The Ultimate Solution with inspiration from SomaMan. Just subclass all your custom buttons and you Get this:

[image]

includes: on tap animation and release and drag away.

```
//
//  CustomFocusButton.swift
//

import UIKit

class CustomFocusButton: UIButton {


let focusedScaleFactor : CGFloat = 1.2
let focusedShadowRadius : CGFloat = 10
let focusedShadowOpacity : Float = 0.25
let shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
let shadowOffSetFocused = CGSizeMake(0, 27)
let animationDuration = 0.2

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
{
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            if self.focused{
                UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, animations:{ [weak self] () -> Void in

                        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
                        weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor, weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor)
                        weakSelf.clipsToBounds = false
                        weakSelf.layer.shadowOpacity = weakSelf.focusedShadowOpacity
                        weakSelf.layer.shadowRadius = weakSelf.focusedShadowRadius
                        weakSelf.layer.shadowColor = weakSelf.shadowColor
                        weakSelf.layer.shadowOffset = weakSelf.shadowOffSetFocused

                    },completion:{ [weak self] finished in

                        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
                        if !finished{
                            weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor, weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor)
                            weakSelf.clipsToBounds = false
                            weakSelf.layer.shadowOpacity = weakSelf.focusedShadowOpacity
                            weakSelf.layer.shadowRadius = weakSelf.focusedShadowRadius
                            weakSelf.layer.shadowColor = weakSelf.shadowColor
                            weakSelf.layer.shadowOffset = weakSelf.shadowOffSetFocused
                        }

                    })
            } else {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, animations:{  [weak self] () -> Void in
                    guard let weakSelf = self else {return}

                    weakSelf.clipsToBounds = true
                    weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                    }, completion: {[weak self] finished in
                        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
                        if !finished{
                            weakSelf.clipsToBounds = true
                            weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                        }
                })
            }
        }, completion: nil)
}

override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in

        guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
        weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        weakSelf.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 10);

    })
}

override func pressesCancelled(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {

    if focused{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
            guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
            weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor, weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor)
            weakSelf.layer.shadowOffset = weakSelf.shadowOffSetFocused
        })
    }

}

override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {

    if focused{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {[weak self] () -> Void in

            guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
            weakSelf.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor, weakSelf.focusedScaleFactor)
            weakSelf.layer.shadowOffset = weakSelf.shadowOffSetFocused
        })
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found something better:

```c
-(void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
    [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
        if (self.focused) {
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else {
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is self referring to? is this a subclass method?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 /tvOS11 and better:**

Set the ButtonType in the Interface Builder button properties to "Plain".

Add this private extension to your class:

```
private extension UIImage {

    static func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

Then in your connected IBOutlet set the background image for the focused state of the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        let backgroundImageSelected = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .red, size: myButton.bounds.size)
        myButton.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSelected, for: .focused)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIButton` method `setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?, forState state: UIControlState)` and pass through an image that is a flat color and the state `.Normal`.

This image can easily be created programatically from a `UIColor` and a size of 1x1:

```
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background image in storyboard to an image that contains the color you would like