# tvOS - UIButton doesn't animate when focused

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos

I have a small test app for tvOS - a white background with two buttons. The buttons are standard `UIButton`s, with no customization except setting the title text and setting `titleColor` to black.

My `UIButton`s do not receive a shadow (or any animation at all) when they become focused. If I replace them with `UITextField`s, they get the default drop shadow and animation as expected. I can confirm that the buttons **do** become focused by adding a target and printing to console when they are selected.

Any idea what's going on? [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html), [this article](http://nerds.airbnb.com/tvos-focus-engine/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720862/how-can-i-create-a-button-with-a-background-color-for-tvos-while-still-showing-f) all suggest that `UIButton` should automatically receive the default focus animation just like the other focusable elements. Is this a bug or something that I'm missing?

Relevant code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(500, 500, 300, 100)
    view.addSubview(button)

    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.setTitle("Button2", forState: .Normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(900, 500, 300, 100)
    view.addSubview(button2)

}
```

**EDIT:** This occurs ONLY when adding the `UIButton`s programmatically - if I add them in Interface Builder, they function correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling that `UIButton()` initializer will get you a 'custom' button, when what you really want is a 'system' button, like so:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
```

Custom buttons don't get any built-in appearance at all, while system buttons do.