# tvOS System UIButton parallax effect

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, parallax, tvos

I have a UIButton and a UIImageView with an image on the first view of a tvOS app.   It's a system UIButton with no image associated with it, and the app is Objective-C.

I've looked all over the place, but can not figure out why it's not getting a parallax effect on the UIButton.   The button itself works fine, and animates a press when I press the controller, and segues as expected.

Am I incorrect in assuming it's supposed to have a parallax effect by default?  Am I supposed to add this myself?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Custom `UIButton`'s do not get the *free* effects that a system button gets. You have to create these effects yourself.

Comment: Here's an example of how to implement the effects yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35206995/2108547

Comment: We created controls and extensions that can be used to easly add parallax effect to any UIView https://github.com/PGSSoft/ParallaxView

Comment: just for anyone coming to this very old question!  what Daniel said above @DanielStorm is no longer true, it's now built in.  simply set `.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true`

Answer (score 1):

#### For 2022. Fortunately it's now trivial.

1, In storyboard have a normal UIButton. In the attributes inspector of the button, just **select the image as normal** from the drop-down. That's it.

- Use one of your own images (i.e., a photo of a cat, etc)
- or just use one of the SFSymbols if you want.
- It makes **no difference** if the button is set to system, custom, etc. Use any settings you wish.

2, Then you must do this in code:

```
thatButton.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
```

It's annoying but **you cannot do (2) on storyboard**. You have to add a line of code. It's just how it is.

(Of course, often you would just do it in your button subclass, either way.)

#### However ...

Be aware that you will still suffer the weird scaling problem with images in tvOS. When using adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused, they really won't scale properly for you.  contentMode is ignored.

#### Multilayer image ...

If you want to have an actual **parallaxing** image. It's easy. Make an image stack. You have to put in at **two** layers minimum. Note that you don't have to have three unless you want to. For a simple test just have the rear one as "a black rectangle" and the middle one as your normal PNG image of your logo or whatever.

In step "1" above just select that image stack ("image stacks" are just images, they are listed the same).

Note that you absolutely do not have to have an image stack. It's completely normal to just have "a plain image". Note that for example, many of Apple's own buttons are, simply, a PNG and not an image stack.  For example the "controls" one (with the gears) is an image stack. But many are just plain flat PNGs, no parallax.